# 'dotnet --version' is returning 'You must install or update .NET to run this application.'

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, sdk

I have installed .net SDK 6.0.419 from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0). After installing when I ran 'dotnet --version' I encountered below error.

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application
App: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.419\dotnet.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.27' (x64)
.NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\

No frameworks were found.

Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.27&arch=x64&rid=win-x64&os=win10
```

Also when I run list sdk,runtime commands, I'm getting the below versions without any error.

```
C:\Users\sharmapulkit> dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.27 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

C:\Users\sharmapulkit> dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.419 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [download the sdk here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-6.0.27-windows-x64-installer) and install it.

Then you can run `dotnet --list-runtimes` command, if you can see `Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.27` like below, then you can run the web application.

[image]

Comment: Not working for me, also the link you have shared is not for sdk it is for runtime.

Comment: Worked for me after re-installing this.